# Is there a way to initialize an array with an enumeration of integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way in Java to do something like:

int foo[] = new int[0..n];

i.e

foo[0] = 0

foo[3] = 3

Comment: Unfortunately not :'( Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950386/is-there-anything-like-enumerable-rangex-y-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Not using built-in language features. You can easily write a method to do it, of course, but there's nothing built-in - and I suspect that it's sufficiently rarely useful that it's not in many third party utility libraries (such as Guava) either.

Comment: The closest Guava-based alternative is `Range.closed(0, 3).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers()).asList()`.  That's a mouthful, but that's because you really ought to just do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you could use a simple for-loop:

```
int foo[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) foo[i] = i;
```

And if you want a method try something like this:

```
public void initialize(int[] array, int start, int end) {
    int array_length = array.length;
    if (end > array_length) end = array_length;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        array[i - start] = i;
    }
}

// In any other point in your code
int foo[] = new int[6];
initialize(foo, 0, 10);
```

Another way would be to make a Range class to add this functionality:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Range implements Iterable<Integer> {
    Integer array[];

    public Range(int size) {
        this(0, size - 1);
    }

    public Range(int start, int end) {
        array = new Integer[end - start];

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            array[i - start] = i;
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> asList() {
        return Arrays.asList(array);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return Arrays.asList(array).iterator();
    }
}
```

Here is an usage example:

```
Range range = new Range(4, 10);

for (int i : range) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I'm sure that this code can be improved but it isn't worth it.

Comment: +1, but that probably should be `[n+1]` and `i <= n`. At least, I'd expect that a notation like the OP's `new int[0..n]` would include both endpoints, `0` and `n`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but would be easier to declare n as n+1 xD Anyway, is a simple example to say that what he is looking for is not possible. Thanks for your comment anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 10;
int[] arr = new int[n+1];
```

`for` loops has flexible syntax, so you can do even this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; arr[i] = i++ );
```

P.S. 
If you want less code than above, you can do this:

```
int i = 0;
for ( int c : arr ) { arr[i] = i++; }
```

P.P.S. 
Despite the fact that these pieces of code are laconic, for me they seems unclear, and smells bad.