# Generating and consuming an array within a StringTemplate-4 template

Tags: stringtemplate-4

I'm new to *StringTemplate4* and probably I am going to ask something overly simple, impossible or stupid but I couldn't find any other information on it.
So far, I have set this minimal set of templates:

```
define(name,arity) ::= "<name>(<vars(arity)>)."
vars(n) ::= "<n:var();separator=\", \">"
var(n) ::= "V<n>"
```

and I would like to get:

```
pred(V1, V2, V3).
```

by calling the following code:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile(...);
ST st = group.getInstanceOf("define");
st.add("name", "pred");
st.add("arity", 3);
String result = st.render();
```

Is it possible? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringTemplate doesn't have built-in operators for repeating. Instead, you'll need to iterate, like described in the following question.

[Is there anything like Enumerable.Range(x,y) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2950386/138304)

Keep in mind that you'll need to pass an `Iterator<T>` and not an `Iterable<T>` due to a current limitation in StringTemplate (the interpreter supports `Collection<T>`, but not `Iterable<T>`). If you want to use the built-in iteration variable `i` or `i0`, you could also pass an appropriately sized `new Object[n]`.

Comment: Hi Sam, many thanks for the reply. Since there are no repeating operators, even a simple `int v[] = {1, 2, 3}` would do the trick, but probably the `Iterator` requires some little coding but uses less memory... Since I'll probably will have to pass a further array of strings whose arity is exactly the `n` in my example, how I am supposed to use the `<i>` or `<i0>` to generate my sequence of variables? The only reference I could find is [here](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ST4/StringTemplate+cheat+sheet) and I didn't quite get what to do... cheers!