# Printing 1 to 100 without using loops or condition in java

Tags: java

I want to display 1 to 100 without using loops. 
I already tried storing 1-100 in array but it also requires use of loops.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: With all due respect. This makes absolutely no sense. You will need atleast one "conditional check" to see if the value is 100.

Comment: The key here is recursion (try it). But as TheLostMind said, you'll need at least one conditional check.

Comment: can we do it without using loops. if so please tell me how

Comment: `System.out.println("1");System.out.println("2");System.out.println("3");...System.out.println("99");System.out.println("100");`

Comment: @Pallav - You can do it using recursion as *Paco* says. But without *conditional* check. Nopes.. Note that using recursion is almost always *inefficient*.

Comment: Maybe [printing from a file stream](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2950638/205233) will do the trick.

Comment: @Pallav You can write 100 `System.out.println()` statements

Comment: Use Clojure code from java with (range 1 100) in it. Same trick can be done with Scala etc.

Comment: @Jens nice one .. :D but your way is too hard to follow :D

Comment: will try recursion... thanks @Paco Abato

Comment: @Pallav You can also do `System.out.println("1,2,3,4,5..."); `

Comment: Marked it as exactly [Duplicate of Display numbers from 1 to 100 without loops or conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044033/display-numbers-from-1-to-100-without-loops-or-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (***Java 8***)

```
IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(n -> { System.out.println(n); });
```

However, *implementation* of `range()` as well as `forEach()` uses *loops*, so, the solution may be on the *edge of cheating*.

If you consider the code above as *cheating*, you can *emulate* loop, via, say, *recursion*:

```
private static void printIt(int n) {
  System.out.println(n);

  if (n < 100)
    printIt(n + 1);
}

...

printIt(1);
```

Comment: You are using a loop. OP ask for a solution with out using loops.

Comment: But that `forEach`... I mean... Technically speaking... It is still a loop ;D

Comment: Eh... Technically, `forEach` is not a *loop* by itself, its a *method* which, however, uses a loop... Actually, `range()` should use loop as well. So the solution is on the edge of cheating

Answer (score 0):

Use toString() method like this:

```
System.out.println(array.toString());
```

It converts array to this:

```
[1,2,3,4...]
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: But you need a loop to fill the array.

Comment: You can initialize array like this: `int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5...}`

Comment: Than you cal also write 100 `System.out.println()` statements.

Comment: Yes you can, but this is shorter

Comment: if you will have it short you can use `System.out.println("1,2,3,4,5...");`

Comment: This looks like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Code

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, ... , 100 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 100]
```

[Java.util.Arrays.toString(int[ ]) Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_int.htm)

Comment: You have to declare an array 100 values if you want to print values without using any loop and condition.

Answer (score 0):

You never said it had to print them only once or that program had to terminate successfully:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    print(0);
}

private static void print(int i)
{
    System.out.println((i % 100) + 1);
    print(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(100);
}

private static void print(int n) {
    if(n > 1) {
        print(n-1);
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] i = {1,10,50};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
  }
```